# Skip a version of a package

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I recently upgraded VirtualBox to version 5.1.16 and found that it has a bug<sup>1</sup>, so I downgraded back to 5.1.14.  Now I would like both `apt upgrade` and Linux Mint 17.3's Update Manager<sup>2</sup> to stop trying to get me to upgrade to this version of this package.

I know I could ignore updates for that package in Update Manager, and even better, [pin the package in apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35560/ignore-package-in-update-manager), but I don't want to be stuck on 5.1.14 forever<sup>3</sup>.  I'm hoping that when 5.1.18 comes out, that this bug will be fixed, and if not that version, then 5.1.20, etc.  So I'd like to be notified when the *next* version is available, which won't happen if I ignore updates for this package.

I know that I could rely on VirtualBox itself to inform me of updates, but first of all, I rarely start the main VirtualBox Manager, usually just starting VMs directly via shortcuts (so I'll rarely get a chance to get notified by VirtualBox).  More importantly, I'm more interested in a general solution that doesn't rely on the package in question checking for updates itself.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you're curious about the bug, on my Windows 7 guest, symbolic links to directories within a shared folder on the host aren't working correctly.  I get an error when I try to descend into any subdirectories within them.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> I'm still using 17.3 because I use the KDE edition, and Plasma 5, which the 18 series comes with, is still too unstable to use a daily driver (after nearly 3 years!).</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> Or until such time that I remember to undo the pin.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a pin or a hold to force `apt` to stay on a specific version of a package, you can pin with a negative priority to prevent `apt` from considering a specific version (or version pattern):

```
Package: virtualbox
Pin: version 5.1.16*
Pin-Priority: -1
```

With this saved in *e.g.* `/etc/apt/preferences.d/virtualbox`, and perhaps the package name corrected, `apt` will ignore any packages of 5.1.16 but will consider other versions: 5.1.14 which you already have installed, 5.1.18 etc.