# Why the pin priority is applied to all versions of a package, even if I specify one?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, software-installation, software-updates

Suppose I have the following situation for `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux`:

`skypeforlinux:
  Installed: 8.11.0.4
  Candidate:  8.13.0.2
  Version table:
     8.13.0.2 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.11.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages`

However, now I want to skip version 8.13.0.2 because I know it's bugged. So, following some recommendations found around (including [Skip a version of a package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350282/skip-a-version-of-a-package)), I create `/etc/apt/preferenced.d/skype.pref` and type:

`Package: skypeforlinux
Pin: version 8.13.0.2
Pin-Priority: -1`

(please note I don't see any difference in behaviour if I add a trailing `*` to the version number).

This is now the output of `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux`:

`skypeforlinux:
  Installed: 8.11.0.4
  Candidate:  8.11.0.4
  Package-Pin: 8.13.0.2
  Version table:
     8.13.0.2 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.11.0.4 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0.4 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.0.1 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.0.1 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages`

What puzzles me is that the -1 priority is assigned to all versions. The effect right now is that version 8.13.0.2 is not proposed for upgrade, but if I slightly change my skype.pref so that I PIN, say, version 8.9.0.1, I still get:

`skypeforlinux:
  Installed: 8.11.0.4
  Candidate:  8.11.0.4
  Package-Pin: 8.9.0.1
  Version table:
     8.13.0.2 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.11.0.4 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0.4 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.0.1 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.0.1 -1
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages`

and version 8.13.0.2 is not proposed for upgrade (the candidate version is still 8.11.0.4, which is the installed one). So, it seems like whatever version I write in `skype.pref`, all versions of this package are assigned priority -1, while I would like it to be assigned just to the buggy version 8.13.0.2.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 (based on Ubuntu 14.04), `apt-get` version 1.0.1ubuntu2 (brought by package `apt` version 1.0.1ubuntu2.17).
`/etc/preferences` is empty. In `/etc/preferences.d` I have the following files:

```
# getdeb.pref
Package: *
Pin: origin archive.getdeb.net
Pin-Priority: 250

# official-package-repositories.pref
Package: *
Pin: origin live.linuxmint.com
Pin-Priority: 750

Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint,c=upstream
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 500

# official-extra-repositories.pref
Package: *
Pin: origin build.linuxmint.com
Pin-Priority: 700
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Just edited my question to add information about my environment. I'm on Linux Mint 17.3 (based on Ubuntu 14.04), `apt-get` version 1.0.1ubuntu2. What kind of settings/files should I post to see if something is interfering?

Comment: Using Debian 8 and apt 1.0.9.8.4 it did behave more or less like you described, despite examples in `man apt_preferences` . So these versions of apt are seriously wrong with regard to pinning. My advice: upgrade to a newer release

Comment: @A.B I've added the contents of all the pref files in the question. I'll try to search for apt changelogs to see if I can find any bug report that may explain this behaviour.

Comment: This could be a good candidate bug to explain this behaviour: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770017 
Seems to be fixed in version 1.1~exp9. See also: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2/changelog

Comment: Indeed, even if there's no regex here, having a new algorithm starting from 1.1~exp9 must have fixed it too.